# Has there ever been a month with 32 days?

Tags: calendar, modern

As the title says. I *believe* (and correct me if I'm wrong) that with our modern Gregorian calendar, no month will ever be longer than 31 days.

But have there been any times in the (perhaps recent) past where we had 32 days in a month?

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: It was apparently possible with the Julian Calendar due to the [Leap Year error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar#Leap_year_error).

Comment: In Republican Rome (ok, not very recent) the calendar was not set in stone but determined by the pontifex, who would sometimes enlarge or shrink it for political motives (delay or precipitate the elections of new consuls, for example). Maybe that would have caused a 32 days month.

Comment: And I think, only the variant of @SJuan76 works, for other calendars than Julian/Gregorian have not official, but astronomic months, if any. And the change from Julian to Gregorian SHORTENS months. Or some other ruler could do that, Rome Emperor, Constantinople Emperor or a pope.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems the Julian calendar had [a month with 32 days on leap years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar) at one point:

> An [inscription](https://epigraphy.packhum.org/text/252886) has been discovered which orders a new calendar to
>   be used in Asia to replace the previous Greek lunar calendar.
>   According to one translation
>
> "Intercalation shall commence on the day after 14 Peritius [a.d. IX
>   Kal. Feb, which would have been 15 Peritius] as it is currently
>   constituted in the third year following promulgation of the decree.
>   Xanthicus shall have 32 days in this intercalary year."
>
> This is historically correct. It was decreed by the proconsul that the
>   first day of the year in the new calendar shall be Augustus' birthday,
>   a.d. IX Kal. Oct. Every month begins on the ninth day before the
>   kalends. The date of introduction, the day after 14 Peritius, was 1
>   Dystrus, the next month. The month after that was Xanthicus. Thus
>   Xanthicus began on a.d. IX Kal. Mart., and normally contained 31 days.
>   In leap year, however, it contained an extra "Sebaste day", the Roman
>   leap day, and thus had 32 days. From the lunar nature of the old
>   calendar we can fix the starting date of the new one as 24 January,
>   a.d. IX Kal. Feb 5 BC in the Julian calendar, which was a leap year.
>   Thus from inception the dates of the reformed Asian calendar are in
>   one-to-one correspondence with the Julian.

Comment: But months do not begin before the Kalends.

Answer (score 12):

Not that I know of, but in 1712 in Sweden, [February had 30 days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_30).

Sweden, being a Protestant country, was initially suspicious of the "papist" Gregorian calendar, but decided to adopt it in the early 18th century. However, there was an idea to do so gradually, by simply skipping all the leap days until the calendars were in synch. This was done in 1700, but then, the Great Northern War broke out and people seemed to forget about this, so 1704 and 1708 had 29 days in February. Then someone realized how silly it all was, and decided to go back to the Julian calendar by adding an extra leap day in 1712.

Sweden eventually shifted to the Gregorian calendary in 1740, but then all in one go.

Comment: Hah, interesting. Thanks. This would make computer programmers' lives hell if this ever happened in the modern world!

Answer (score 9):

Of course it depends whose months you look at. Part of the decimalization project in revolutionary France was Claude Boniface Collignon's proposals for decimalizing time. He called for ten "solar months" per year, each of 36.5 days. See page 168 of his *[Decouverte d'etalons justes, naturels, invariables et universels](https://books.google.com/books?id=WPA4AAAAMAAJ)*. I think his long months only exist conceptually and never became national law.

Comment: Thanks! I don't read French so unfortunately I can't read his full proposal, but it seems to me that having the month change over mid-day could get really awkward. I'm curious how they planned to divide it exactly.

Answer (score 6):

In 46 BC, as part of the introduction of the Julian calendar, Caesar first had to wrench the existing calendar back into alignment with the solar year.  It had drifted so far out of alignment that harvest festivals were separated from the harvest by several months.

[As part of doing this, he introduced two special one-time intercalary months between November and December](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar) that added a total of 67 days to 46 BC.  I haven't been able to find information concerning how the 67 days were split up, but at least one of the months had to have a length of at least 34 days.

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays, [the Tamil calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_calendar#Months)'s month ஆனி (Āni) has 32 days.

Comment: Sources would improve this answer

Comment: Interesting answer. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_calendar

Comment: This answer is incorrect, there are only 31 days in the month AANI (15 June - 15 July), The correct Month would be AADI (16 July - 16 August).

Comment: @JustSaying pleas add a source and make that a new answer or edit this answer

Answer (score 1):

I guess there Is and it happened in 1978 October. It had 32 days. :-)[image]

Comment: Where is this from? What was it printed for? A gag?

Comment: For those wondering, this is an old news clipping regarding a bizarrely printed date of that year in what appears to be a calendar for a Chinese diaspora community. It lists both the Western calendar (Wed, 32 October, 1978) and also the traditional Chinese calendar (1 October, Wuwu). By referencing known calendars, we know that October 1 of Year Wuwu actually corresponds to *November 1* of AD 1978, which is also a Wednesday. In otherwords, this was a misprinted calendar.

Comment: Maybe they wanted to use the Chinese month and the Western day of month intentionally.  Like saying the bars close Friday and Saturday nights at 2600 hours